Org-mode create footnote not working
If I open a new org file and simply type a line, then try C-c C-x f with cursor at the end of the line (or in the middle), a helm-mode-org-footnote-new minibuffer opens with the prompt Label (leave empty for anonymous): But when I hit return -- nothing. Normally, I get a new inserted footnote link at the cursor and the matching entry in the Footnote section at the bottom of the buffer ready for my entry. I can also open an org-mode file with many existing footnotes and similar bizarre behavior -- as it inserts a footnot link of an already existing footnote with no typical jump to the Footnote section. Version 9.7.17 on 29.4. What has happened to break this? BTW, works with a >emacs -Q version.

Since it works with emacs -Q, there is probably something wrong with your init file (you might want to try emacs -q and see if it works there: then you are sure that there is something wrong with your init file).

Typically C-c C-x f is bound to org-footnote-action, so some package you installed probably rebinds it to some helm command.

I commented out (require 'org-ref-helm) out of my org-ref section of my init and it seems to be working again. Not sure why.

Well, check the binding with C-h k C-c C-x f in an Org file, before and after you eval (require 'org-ref-helm). A quick scan of org-ref-helm does not show anything untoward, but @JohnKitchin might know something that would explain what you see.

After evaluating (require 'org-ref-helm) Emacs reports C-c C-x f is undefined. Will inquire by JK.

Was that in an Org mode buffer?

Yes, all tests.
